# How do I deny the DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE permission?

Tags: permissions, screenshots, android-14

If an app requests the DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE permission ([new to Android 14](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features/screenshot-detection)), how can I deny it that permission? I don't want the app to get a SecurityException or anything like that; I just want to make the screen capture callback never fire. Solutions that need ADB or root are acceptable.